# How to use find in Vuex with Module Decorators

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Currently, I'm transferring everything from Vue2 to Vue3 with TypeScript and Module Decorators. I get an error when I want to use the `find` function.

```js
@Module
export default class TagsModule extends VuexModule {
    data = {};
    get AllTag() {
        return (id) => {
            return this.data.find(tag => tag.id === id)
        };
    }
}
```

It says: `Property 'find' does not exist on type '{}'.`

I want to achieve the following:

1. I want to send a string to `AllTag` and use it to search between `data`

Data looks like:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "created_by": 1,
        "status": null,
        "uid": null,
        "name": "Testtaag",
        "class": "light-danger"
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "created_by": 1,
        "status": null,
        "uid": null,
        "name": "tihS",
        "class": "light-warning"
    }
]
```

Comment: In your code example, `data` is an object. Objects don’t have a `find` method. Arrays do, though: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: What is the best way to proceed?

Comment: By using an array if you want to use array methods…

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `data` as `data = {};`. This is an object, so the array `find` method makes no sense. If you want to store an array (like your example shows), use `data = [];`.